# foreach array and update

Tags: php, arrays

I am struggling with updating values inside an array when looping foreach. All I get is the last record.

```
$books = array(
  (int) 0 => array(
    'Page' => array(
        'id' => '30',
        'order' => '0'
    )
),
  (int) 1 => array(
    'Page' => array(
        'id' => '4',
        'order' => '1'
    )
),
  (int) 2 => array(
    'Page' => array(
        'id' => '7',
        'order' => '2'
    )
),
  (int) 3 => array(
    'Page' => array(
        'id' => '36',
        'order' => '4'
    )
)
)
```

I am trying to update the ['Page']['order'] to start at 0 and increment by one.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($books as $book) {
    $book['Page']['order'] = $i;
    $i++;
};
```

Comment: `foreach ($books as &$book)`

Comment: sorry, still just get only one record left in the $book afterwards array(1) { ["Page"]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "36" ["order"]=> int(3) } }

Comment: sorry you are right, I was looking at $book when I should have looked at $books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($books as $book) {
    $books[$book]['Page']['order'] = $i;
    $i++;
};
```